# LaTeX booktabs horizontal oveflow

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am new to LaTeX and I want to create a quite simple table (in german). As you can see in my code, it has to contain 5 rows and 5 columns. My problem is that the table is too large for my page and it overflows on the right side of the page. I don't want to rotate the table, so it should use hyphenation to use the given space better.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={3cm},rmargin={2cm},
tmargin={2cm},bmargin = {2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\end{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Übersicht aller Umfragen zur Landtagswahl in Sachsen-Anhalt im April/Mai 2021.}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l}
\toprule
  Durchgeführt von: 
  & Erhebungszeitraum 
  & Datum der Veröffentlichung 
  & Erhebungsmethode(n) 
  & Veröffentlicht von:\\
\midrule
  infratest dimap 
  & 16. – 21.April 2021 
  & 23.April 2021 
  & zufallsbasierte Telefon- und Onlineinterviews 
  & mrd.de \\
  Forsa 
  & 20. – 27.April 2021 
  & 29.April 2021 
  & k.A. 
  & welt.de \\
  Insa 
  & 17. – 23.Mai 2021 
  & 26.Mai 2021 
  & k.A. 
  & bild.de \\
  infratest dimap 
  & 25. – 26.Mai 2021 
  & 27. Mai 2021 
  & zufallsbasierte Telefon- und Onlineinterviews 
  & tagesschau.de \\
  Mannheimer Forschungsgruppe Wahlen 
  & 25. – 27.Mai 2021 
  & 28.Mai 2021 
  & zufallsbasierte Telefoninterviews 
  & zdf.de \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I think a similar problem is described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567849/booktabs-table-overflows-the-page), but to be honest; my table is much simpler (no multicolumns and no math-symbols), so I have some problems to find the right code to solve my problem.

Thank you very much for reading my question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get line breaks you'll need a column type of fixed with, e.g. `p{<some width>}` or you can use the `tabularx` package to automatically determine the width of the columns.

However even with line breaks, the table will still look awfully crowded. You can safe a bit more space by giving the months as numbers instead of words and adding `@{}` before/after the first/last column.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={3cm},rmargin={2cm},
tmargin={2cm},bmargin = {2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Übersicht aller Umfragen zur Landtagswahl in Sachsen-Anhalt im April/Mai 2021.}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *5{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
\toprule
  Durchgeführt von: 
  & Erhebungs\-zeitraum 
  & Datum der Veröffentlichung 
  & Erhebungs\-methode(n) 
  & Veröffentlicht von:\\
\midrule
  infratest dimap 
  & 16. – 21.4.2021 
  & 23.4.2021 
  & zufallsbasierte Telefon- und Onlineinterviews 
  & mrd.de \\
  Forsa 
  & 20.–27.4.2021 
  & 29.4.2021 
  & k.A. 
  & welt.de \\
  Insa 
  & 17.–23.5.2021 
  & 26.5.2021 
  & k.A. 
  & bild.de \\
  infratest dimap 
  & 25.–26.5.2021 
  & 27.5.2021 
  & zufallsbasierte Telefon- und Onlineinterviews 
  & tagesschau.de \\
  Mannheimer Forschungsgruppe Wahlen 
  & 25.–27.5.2021 
  & 28.5.2021 
  & zufallsbasierte Telefoninterviews 
  & zdf.de \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That really worked for me! In addition I used `\begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{-1cm}` from the `changepage` package to give the table more space.

Comment: @theWhiteMarabou Another tough to make the table more compact: you could replace the content in the column "Erhebungsmethode(n)" with symbols of a dice for "zufallsbassiert", a telefon and a globe and write as table note the meaning of the symbols.

Comment: In its current form, the text-to-information ratio of this column is not very good and the same long text repeats often. [Edward Tufte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte) would get a fit :)

Comment: If all your surveys are from 2021, you could leave out the year. It should be clear from the context which year the dates refer to.

Comment: oh. an try out the `caption` package, it gives better spacing around the caption